# Powershell has stopped working when called from .cmd

Tags: powershell-2.0

I am having trouble with calling a .ps1 from .cmd.

The powershell script runs fine on its own (it gets cpu utilisation and uptime from a list of computers in a .txt file & outputs the info as "..\$Server" + ".txt" with one file per argument; it runs against the argument list simultaneously as a background job to speed it up).

The issue is not the powershell script itself - it only has issues when being called from  example.cmd or as a scheduled task (which is effectively the same thing), this causes powershell to crash with the "Powershell has stopped working" dialog box.

Is there a trick to call powershell scripts from a dos prompt without it crashing?

Is it simply because the powershell script runs as a background job causing the issue?

Is Powershell V2.0 the cause?

Thanks in advance.

```
$Scriptblock = {
param
(
    $Server,
    $ExportCSV
)
    $Uptime = (get-date)-([System.Management.ManagementDateTimeconverter]::ToDateTime((Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $Server win32_operatingsystem).lastbootuptime))
        $uptimeval = "$($Uptime.days)d $($Uptime.Hours)h $($Uptime.Minutes)m"

    $Counter = Get-Counter -ComputerName $Server "\Processor(_Total)\% Processor Time"  -MaxSamples 1 
        $CounterSamples = $Counter | % {$_.CounterSamples}
        $CounterSamplesDecimal = "{0:N0}" -f $CounterSamples.cookedvalue

    $MasterArray = @()
        $MasterArray += $CounterSamplesDecimal
        $MasterArray += $CounterSamplesDecimal
        $MasterArray += $uptimeval
        $MasterArray += $Server

    $MasterArray | Out-file -Filepath $ExportCSV 
}
    $Servers = get-content -Path "D:\SERVERS.txt"
    foreach ($Server in $Servers)
{
    $ExportCSVFile = "D:\$Server" + ".txt"
    Start-Job -ScriptBlock $ScriptBlock -ArgumentList @($Server, $ExportCSVFile)
}
```

Comment: Additional info: 
When the script is run directly it lists one job per line and begins the processing of each job in the background no problems, it just takes time for all background jobs to complete.
When called via .cmd it starts to do exactly the same thing on the screen - as in listing one job per argument in the computers.txt file etc, then once it begins to output the result.txt files it crashes.

Comment: sounds as if cmd shell thinks the powershell process timed out. Do you see not responding immediately? How are you calling it by the way?

Comment: Calling like this:

powershell.exe -file "D:\CPU.ps1"

it does fire off the background job - all looks good till the write part happens.